# PHP PDO mysql_result() equivalent?

Tags: php, oop, object, pdo, fetch

What would i use in PDO instead of old mysql_resul()?

```
function ib_uk_isvalid($db,$uk) {
    try {

    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM ib_userkeys WHERE value=:val");
    $sth->bindParam(":val",$uk);
    $sth->execute();
    $numrows = $sth->fetchColumn();

    if($numrows>=1) {

        $sth2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ib_userkeys WHERE value=:val");
        $sth2->bindParam(":val",$uk);
        $sth2->execute();
        $res = $sth2->fetchAll();
        print($res[0]->type);

    } else {
    return 0;
    }


    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        return $e->getMessage();

    }
}

ib_uk_isvalid($db,1234)
```

Gives me error because it returns table instead of an object (which i need).

Comment: That seems rather odd logic. Can't you just do one SELECT, and count the results? As it is, you're running the same query twice....

Comment: @andrewsi Pending the setup - the `count()` may actually be insignificant in terms of execution; the database may cache a relative count and nearly auto-return a result instead of actually counting the rows.

Comment: @newfurniturey - but there's also the overhead of passing the query to the database. True, it's not much extra work, but it's still extra work.

Answer (score 3):

```
function ib_uk_isvalid($db, $uk) {
    $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM ib_userkeys WHERE value = :val LIMIT 1');
    $query->bindValue(':val', $uk);
    $query->execute();

    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    return $row ? $row->type : 0;
}
```

... is how I'd write that. It may fix the problem.